# Pre-installed barcode/qr readers on mobile devices

Tags: barcode, qr-code

There's an idea within my company to put QR codes in some of our marketing literature, and I'm trying to find some stats (or specific device info) to help me make the decision.

My feeling is that, of those clients with a smartphone (BB, iOS, Android, Symbian...) very few of would have either the knowledge or the software (pre-installed) to read a barcode/qr code.

Information that would be useful:

- published results where companies have used QR codes and analysed usage
- a guide to which mobile OSs recognise a barcode natively in the camera app *or* have a specific reader app factory-installed
- any info regarding percentage penetration of barcode reader apps across all mobile OSs
- survey results covering questions such as "would you be able to read a qr code?"

I've found quite a bit of info on mobile OS market share (such as [StatCounter Mobile OS data](http://gs.statcounter.com/#mobile_os-GB-monthly-201003-201103)) but only one article regarding penetration - [Dubit's results of a survey of 1000 UK teens](http://www.dubitresearch.com/blog/2011/qr-codes-could-be-a-winner-with-teens-%E2%80%93-if-only-they-knew-what-to-do-with-them/).

Thanks for all your time!

Adam